# Require files from JSON using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have some `txt` files with some custom content inside. File names are contained inside `JSON`.

```
{
   txtFiles: ['./file1.txt', './file2.txt', './file3.txt']
}
```

I want to `require` them to have an access to their content in `JS`. Something like this:

```
const txtFile = require('json!abracadabra!myJsonFile.json');
console.log(txtFile[0]); // should give me a content of file1.txt, not the path
```

I know I could do some tricks like creating text variable and save it into `.js` file and then `require` it as usual. Like this:

```
// 1. create string variable
const myStringVar = `module.exports = [\'require(\'raw!./file1.txt\')\', ...];`;
// 2. then save this into myTxtFiles.js
// 3. then require the file
const txtFileContents = require('./myTxtFiles.js');
```

This is working, but the solution is kinda tricky and ugly. How to achieve the same in some better way?

Comment: What environment are you working in? Browser, or nodejs / command-line?

Comment: This is done on Node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use node's [fs API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html); in particular, [readFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback)
 and/or [readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_file_options)

You can still require your `.json` containing the list of text files, but you should use `readFile` / `readFileSync` to read the contents of the text files rather than abusing `require`.